# Module.exports returns undefined with Mongoose call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I keep getting an `undefined` return on my `find` call with Mongoose. My result
in my exports file doesn't get logged, but it will work if I return a simple string outside my `Projects.find` call.

I'm passing `req` & `res` and they are logged correctly in my exports file, so don't think they have anything to do with the problem. Any ideas what's going wrong?

**routes.js**

```
var proj = require('./exports/projects');

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    //repsonse: undefined
    console.log('response: ' + proj.test(req, res));
    next();
});
```

**exports/projects.js**

```
var Projects = require('../models/projects');

module.exports = {
    test: function(req, res) {
        Projects.find({'owner':req.user.id}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) return '1';
                if (!result)
                    return null;
                else
                    return result;
        });
    }
};
```

**models/projects.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var shortid = require('shortid');

var Projects = new Schema({
        projectid: String,
        pname: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        owner: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        status: { type: String, default: '0' },
        team: String,
        archived: { type: Boolean, default: '0' },
        created_at: Date
});

Projects.pre('save', function(next) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    this.created_at = currentDate;
    this.projectid = shortid.generate();
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Projects', Projects);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to asynchronous nature of the `Project.find()` method. You are trying to return a value in asynchronous function, which gets completed after some time. Thus is gets undefined value in return while executing `proj.test(req, res)` in `console.log('response: ' + proj.test(req, res));`.

**Solution** 
Need to pass a callback function, which gets executed once the `find` operation is done.

**routes.js**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){

    proj.test(req,res,function(result){
      console.log('response',result);
    });
    next();
});
```

**exports/projects.js**

```
module.exports = {
    test: function(req, res, cb) {
        Projects.find({'owner':req.user.id}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) return cb(1);
                if (!result)
                    return cb(null);
                else
                    return cb(result);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Great answer thanks, I knew it had something to do with that but I had a similar situation with exports and it seemed it didn't need a callback for it, but that must be because a page was rendered instead. Thanks again for the comprehensive answer!